# How do I apply for a tourist visa for Paris?

Tags: visas, paris

I am an Indian citizen planning to go for vacation to Paris,grate if you give me instructions to how to obtain visa.

Comment: Even the most basic research with a search engine will tell you how to do this. If you don't understand the instructions you have already found, we can help with that, but there's little point in our writing out instructions that already exist elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Obtaining a Schengen short-stay visa from the French consulate in India is very simple...

1. Define your itinerary
2. Download the S[chengen Short-Stay Visa Application Form](http://www.vfs-france.co.in/PDF/Short-Stay-Visa-Application-Form.pdf)
3. Get travel insurance (statutory requirement)
4. Get bookings and confirmations
5. Collect financial and lifestyle evidence
6. Complete the application form
7. Schedule [an appointment at the VFS](https://www.vfsvisaonline.com/Global-Appointment/Account/RegisteredLogin?q=shSA0YnE4pLF9Xzwon/x/BGxVUxGuaZP3eMAtGHiEL1HYa4RABQTpbLPa5B1NjCChJbdNRfwbVZNGr4USJFAoA==)
8. Attend appointment, pay fee, submit documents

Await results.